# The object ... passed as an argument is not an environment

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

I'm learning scheme using the MIT scheme interpreter. I was working on different representations of vectors and wanted to write a general vector function that takes a list of components, and then returns a function which depending on the argument will return the tag data or the component list.

My code is as follows:

```
(define (vec li)
  (lambda (x)
    (cond ((= x 0) (cons 'vector 
                         (cnt li)))
          ((= x 1) li)))
  (define (cnt li cn)
    (cond ((eq? li '()) cn)
          (else (cnt (cdr li) 
                     (+ cn 1)))))
```

The inner function `(cnt li cn)` counts the number of items in the list and returns the count when the `'()` is reached.
The function returned then allows for access to the tag data with arg 0 or the component list with arg 1

When I try to apply the function with `(vec '(1 0 0))` I get "the object (1 0 0), passed as an argument to vec, is not an environment" I don't understand what an argument as being an environment means nor why I cant pass the list in this manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues:

You're missing a closing bracket (probably c/p error)

You define `cnt` to take 2 parameters,

```
(define (cnt li cn)
  (cond ((eq? li '()) cn)
       (else (cnt (cdr li) 
                  (+ cn 1)))))
```

but when you call it in your main function you only call it with 1 argument.

```
(cnt li)
```

Comment: So I have a tag function `(tag vec)` `(define (tag vec) (car vec))` that returns the tag of a vector. the tags are of the form `(vector . n)` with n being the number of components in the vector. say we have the vector `(define test (vec '(1 2 3))` it would have the tag (vector . 3). why does `(eq? '(vector . 3) (tag test))` return #f?

Comment: I'm not  a Scheme expert, but I think you'll have to write your own equals? function that's a bit more intelligent than the built-in eq?. Something that checks if it's input is a pair?, number?, symbol?, null? etc and then recursively calls equals? on the respective car's and cdr's . Look around a bit on the web, you'll find enough info.

Comment: ill try that later then

Comment: @Jordan Scheme includes a built-in `equal?` function that does that sort of thing.